# OnClick Dropdown works in FireFox but not Chrome or IE?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

The following code works perfectly in Firefox, but not in IE or Chrome... Any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_div(show){
   document.getElementById('passenger1').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('passenger2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('passenger3').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<select name="#" id="#">
      <option selected="selected"> </option>
      <option onClick="display_div('passenger1');">1</option>
      <option onClick="display_div('passenger2');">2</option>
      <option onClick="display_div('passenger3');">3</option>
</select>

<div id="passenger1" style="display:none;"> hey, 1 works </div>
<div id="passenger2" style="display:none;"> hey, 2 works </div>
<div id="passenger3" style="display:none;"> hey, 3 works </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `onChange function`

http://jsfiddle.net/WmEAp/

Comment: Unfortunately this means your javascript call won't go off a second time if you select the same option.  Anyone know of a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

move the "onClick" from options to the select element

```
<select onchange="this(this.selectedIndex)">
    <option value="passenger1">1</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

onclick on option is not a valid click handler. Use onchange on the select instead.

Answer (score 0):

IE and Chrome don't recognize events on option elements of a select.  You can remove the onclick events from your options and add the following onchange event to your select element to get it to work with your current code:

```
onchange="display_div('passenger' + this.value);"
```