# Checkbox .onClick not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write code to make a text box appear and disappear based on whether or not a checkbox is checked, but while it works exactly the way I want it to in chrome, .onclick and .onchange seem to do nothing in firefox.

Trigger code:

```
document.getElementById('Other').onclick = ChangeOtherState;
```

'Other' html code:

```
<p>
  <label for="Other">Other</label> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="Other" class="Types[]" value="Other"/>
  <textarea id="OtherText" name="Other">Please enter other types here</textarea> 
</p>
```

State change function:

```
 function ChangeOtherState() { 

var otherCB = document.getElementById("Other");
var otherTB = document.getElementById('OtherText');

if (otherCB.checked) {
    otherTB.style.display='block';
    otherTB.removeAttribute('disabled');
} else {
    otherTB.style.display='none';
    otherTB.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
};
}
```

Is there a way to make .onclick/onchange work? if not what can I use to get the same functionality without jQuery?

EDIT: For future readers, try to change the position of the trigger declaration to right after initialization.

Comment: Works [fine for me in FF dev](https://jsfiddle.net/oqnm7617/).

Comment: It seems to work if I change the position to be right on initialization, I'm not really sure why the rest of the code would prevent it from working, I guess that's as good a solution as any.

Comment: The "trigger code" needs to happen at a point *after* the checkbox has actually been added to the DOM. In the jsfiddle, by default code is set up in a "load" handler, so it happens when the whole DOM is ready. If you put that code in a plain `<script>` block somewhere *before* the checkbox HTML, then it *won't* be in the DOM and the `.getElementById()` call won't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please find here others topics talking about the issue.

[select onclick onchange not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707190/select-onclick-onchange-not-working)
[onchange / onclick in a checkbox doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117716/onchange-onclick-in-a-checkbox-doesnt-work-in-ie)
[OnClick Dropdown works in FireFox but not Chrome or IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194010/onclick-dropdown-works-in-firefox-but-not-chrome-or-ie)

It seems to have workaround already discussed.

Regards,

Comment: There's no apparent problem in the first place.

Comment: I'v checked all but one of those before I posted the question, but I can't add the onchange to the html element, it has to be in a separate file.